# Why is my GitLab lead_time_for_changes metric returning null?

Tags: gitlab, metrics

I am trying to query some gitlab metrics for a project.

```
 curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-xxx-xxx-1VGj" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxx/dora/metrics?metric=lead_time_for_changes"
[{"date":"2023-02-28","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-01","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-02","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-06","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-08","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-10","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-13","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-14","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-15","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-20","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-23","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-24","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-27","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-28","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-30","value":null},{"date":"2023-03-31","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-04","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-05","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-12","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-13","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-17","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-20","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-21","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-24","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-25","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-26","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-27","value":null},{"date":"2023-04-28","value":null},{"date":"2023-05-02","value":null},{"date":"2023-05-05","value":null},{"date":"2023-05-16","value":null},{"date":"2023-05-23","value":null}]
```

the results return null.

other metric queries are fine, and return data, but `lead_time_for_changes` returns null.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

CICD analytics page in the UI also doesn't show any data for Lead Time for Changes.